# How to avoid "The action you have requested is not allowed" error with Knockout postJson function call

Tags: codeigniter, post, knockout.js, csrf-protection, codeigniter-form-helper

CodeIgniter gives an error "The action you have requested is not allowed." when it fails the check for CSRF. As I understand it, this means the POST is missing the hidden token from the form that proves that an attack is not being done.

The token is generated automatically with a call to the CI form_open function.

In my case, I'm using Knockout to post the contents of a ViewModel for saving, like this:

```
ko.utils.postJson($("form")[0], self.pages);
```

I've found solutions elsewhere that simply turn off the CSRF setting for the specific page, but that doesn't seem like a good solution.

Presumably because the token is not being received, the postJson call is not submitting the existing form. Is there a way to either submit the required token along with the JSON data or submit the JSON data with the existing form?

Comment: In general, this warning message indicates you are trying to access your controller with a POST HTTP verb while there's no POST action defined on your controller. Could you check this? Also have you confirmed setting of the CSRF solves your problem?

Comment: @Anzeo, I can confirm that turning off CSRF fixes the issue, and the value of $_POST is ok in that case. I'm not sure what you mean about there being "no POST action defined" on my controller; there is a test to see if $_POST is set, with an associated action, if that's what you mean.

Comment: I've found that I can work around this problem by setting a form field to contain the result of ko.utils.stringifyJson(self.pages); but to get that working I needed to reference json2.js. It isn't elegant, and I wish I knew a better way of doing it.

Comment: Could you post your form HTML and controller code  so I can have a look at them?

Answer (score 1):

try to use `form_open()` and `form_close`

all form helper functions that will help.

or: I think it's from time zone difference as the `Security` class depends on time for hashing.