# Pyrocms post request 505 error?

Tags: php, codeigniter, pyrocms

Using PyroCMS, I send a `POST` request that returns a HTTP 505. If I send `GET` request on same url is is working.

This is my route file code.

```
$route['admin/pms(/:any)?'] = 'admin$1';
```

This is url i send.

```
http://domain.com/index.php/admin/pms/index/2?
```

Why doesn't `POST` work?

Comment: HTTP 505 error means ["version not supported"](http://www.checkupdown.com/status/E505.html). Are you sure this is what you are getting? Can you check the headers and see what error message you get?

Comment: i got this error in header. `The action you have requested is not allowed.`

Comment: Are you posting with JavaScript? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13924740/how-to-avoid-the-action-you-have-requested-is-not-allowed-error-with-knockout

Comment: yes dear. i send request using javascript.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Action you have requested is not allowed error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10383483/action-you-have-requested-is-not-allowed-error)

Comment: This error is got bout csrf protection. if i remove csrf code it is working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include the CSRF hash name in your POST request:

```
$.post(
  SITE_URL + 'module/controller/function',
  {
    data: data,
    otherdata: somemoredata,
    csrf_hash_name: $.cookie('csrf_cookie_name')
  },
  function() { console.log('Yay'); }
);
```

Check out system/cms/config.php, setting $config['csrf_cookie_name'], to see what your cookie name is. 'csrf_cookie_name' is the default.

Other "solution" would be to turn off CSRF protection.